# Stripe Collect and Payout

Tags: stripe-payments

Trying to integrate Stripe Collect & Payout logic in my application.
The idea is like in Uber... there are Contractors and Providers, when Contractor finish the Job, platform should transfer money from Provider's account into Contractor's, and charge some fee for service...

Stripe declares that it supports this scenario, and I found it in documentation here

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

But it is snot very clear...
My steeps are...

1. Create express account for contractor, than generate link and force user to process express account
2. Create express account for provider, than generate link and force user to process express account
3. Now I thought I can just create PaymentIntent from account to account, but it does not seems to work.. PaymentIntent requires customer class, which I don't have, and unable to find it in documentation

Could you please help to understand

- What is wrong in my logic?
- If I need to create a customer object for Provider, what is the idea behind the customer? it requires balance and other fields, some of which are already in account... there are some fields in customer, like balance, and other... what should be filled here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Customer` is an object that collects information about the person paying for the service. You can provide their email address or their name, and any other relevant information (billing and shipping address, phone, etc.). A Customer has one or multiple `PaymentMethod` which allow them to pay for a service.

The `Account` is an object that collect information about the individual (or company) providing the service. It collects personal information about that person so that Stripe can accept payments on their behalf and send them their money. It will collect things like their name and address but also their bank account details or their SSN for example. This is required to meet regulations and requirements for money movement.

If you take the Uber example, the contractor here is a driver. The sign up for an Express account on your platform and you get an `Account` with the id `acct_12345` that is associated with them. Stripe collects all relevant information during the onboarding flow to let them receive funds.

Similarly, the provider here is the person ordering a ride. They are going to the airport and you need to charge them $20 on behalf of the driver. So you collect their card details and create a `Customer` with the id `cus_123` to represent them.

To charge them $20 you create a `PaymentIntent` with the id `pi_123` and you set the amount to $20 and the currency to USD. When you do this you can also associate the payment with your existing customer which is useful as they are likely to ask for future rides and you want to keep track of all of them. This is done by passing the `customer` parameter as `customer: "cus_123"`. Since the ride is on behalf of the connected account, you also pass `transfer_data` to indicate where to send the funds when the payment succeeds.

The customer concept is entirely optional here but it is useful if you want to save card details and re-use them in the future. When they order the ride with Uber, you don't want them to re-enter all their personal information and card details for every ride because it's too slow and they might just give up. So you save the information so that next time they just have to press one button to order the ride!

You can read more about saving card details during a payment in this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

It's important to understand that in Stripe's vocabulary, the Customer represents the person who pays and the Account represents the person who gets the funds. Staying with your example, when an Uber driver travels to another state, they might order an Uber ride themselves. In that case, you need to create a Customer for them which is entirely separate from the Account they have to receive funds.

Comment: Thanks @koopajah for great explanation, one more question... can I use connect to collect information about customer as well, or I just need to put Stripe Elements (like credit card) to  fill than information and create Customer myself? Also ... I see than on Connect form, there are some fields that write need information later... how should my platform handle later validation?

Comment: and another question, how to check that user has money, and accept the hold only when client accept the drive? should I create PaymentIntent with the Manual accept_type, and manually accept it somehow? How can I verify that there is enough money on customers card?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan You collect the customer details yourself in your form or mobile app, and then pass it to the API. Connect onboarding is specifically for the connected account. As for future information, Stripe would send you an `account.updated` event on your webhook endpoint and you can email the owner of the account (the contractor) to come and provide more information and redirect them to Stripe with an `AccountLink`. You likely want to talk to Stripe's support team at this point for help though https://support.stripe.com/contact